# 2x "Bibliography" in table of contents

Tags: bibliographies

I have an issue with my bibliographie. For some reason, I have 2x "Bibliographie" in my table of contents :

[image: bibliographie]

To publish my thesis, I have to work with the editor's stylesheet:[dgruyter.sty](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1s1tv0eg9ejluqe/dgruyter.sty?dl=0)

Here is part of my code :

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[main=french]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{key,
author      = {Wilhelm Meyer-Lübke},
title       = {Einführung in das Studium der romanischen Sprachwissenschaft},
year        = {1901},
publisher   = {Winter},
address     = {Heidelberg},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cite{key}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{Bianca}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Here you can find my the [style](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1qz0pqfh8cg5az/bianca.bib?dl=0) I used.

Any idea why there are 2 "Bibliography" lines in my table of contents ?
I'd appreciate your help in resolving this problem.

Comment: As is customary on this site, please make your code snippet an MWE (minimal working example). That is, it should be both complete, i.e. compilable as is, (yours is missing an `\end{document}`, the `dgruyter` package is not on CTAN and the bibliography files are missing (both style and content)) and it should be as concise as possible. (Do you really need all those languages and packages to reproduce the problem? Do you need the `\bibliographystyle` and all the packages?) This makes it easier for others to help you. As is, we can't reproduce your problem and thus not help at all.

Comment: @schtandard Sorry for forgetting the \end{document} and for forgetting to join the bibliography and the style files ; I added them now. Yes, I have to work with these packages and with this customized bibliography style, it's imposed by the editor. dgruyter package is not on CTAN because you can only download it on the dgruyter website, that's why I added a link to it in my post.

Comment: Please make your bibliography have one entry and post its contents here.  Please make your style file as short as possible and post its contents here.  See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/107497

Comment: The MWE does not have a table of contents. However, when I add one (`\tableofcontents` directly after `\begin{document}`) it compiles correctly, i.e., only one entry is shown for _Bibliographie_. Did you check if the MWE actually produces the issue on your system, or does it only show on your full document?

Comment: @Marijn I checked the .toc file and for some reason there is    \contentsline {schapter}{Bibliographie}{279}{chapter*.61}% and here after    \contentsline {chapter}{Bibliographie}{279}{chapter*.61}%. I guess it has to do with this?

Comment: your small example would never produce a "chapter 61". Did you actually test that your minimal example demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I found the problem. It happened because of a clash between a package I used in the original thesis and the stylesheet the editor imposed for the publication. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. In the future, please make sure to always post and MWE (remember, complete and minimal) that actually reproduces your problem alongside questions. As you noticed here, that may already help you to identify the problem yourself and helps us help you if it doesn't.